# console debuger router I get connection refused

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, symfony-3.4

I am trying to check the connection that i have on local , but i got refused (something seems related to security). 
So I try >>> sudo console debuger:router 
the reply is : 3109@localhost: Connection refused . 
I am following that tutorial (https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3/routing-wildcards#play) its[image] about symfony , i just did typically the same as he said . but i am not getting the same result .
MoreOver , When Routing to local host on a class controller , localhost wouldnt find it . 
Can anyOne help me please . 
thank you

1. I am using symfony version 3.4.9
2. i am using ubuntu OS 16.04
3. I will attach a photo to demonstrate the issue .
4. PhpStorm IDE

Comment: I would start from renaming method `ShowAction` to `index` lowercase matter! And this question has nothing to do with phpstorm and ubuntu, just php and symfony

Comment: @Alex would you please help to get better to this environment . and please explain to me why lower case matters ? thank you

Comment: @markdibe, You can mark my answer as correct if it could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrong Annotation:

```
/** @
  * Route("/genus/{genusName}")
  */
```

The tutorial code and the right annotation like:

```
/**
  * @Route("/genus/{genusName}")
  */
```

You have to write the annotation on the right way ;)

Comment: excellent man , thank you very mush , i didnt think the answer would be that easy . 
Would you please help me to improve my skills faster in this environment . because i am totally new here , i used to build all my apps usinf microsoft softwares from c# to asp and others , suddenly i have changed my work . and the environment in the new job is totally different

Comment: this framework symfony has one of the best documentation on this planet ! https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html
If you have a special questions, you can ask this on stackoverflow.com :)